# How to add my module to travis-ci pythonpath

Tags: python, python-import, travis-ci

I'm setting up Travis-CI for my project, and oddly, I can't import my project:

```
$ python tests/tests.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tests/tests.py", line 11, in <module>
    from my_module.lib.importer import build_module_list
ImportError: No module named my_module.lib.importer
```

In production, I just create a symlink like so:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/my_module /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/my_module
```

But I don't know -- or want to know, really -- Travis-CI's folder structure.

This seems like a solved problem, but I'm new to Travis-CI. What's the best way to make this work, so my code is added as an importable module?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> What's the best way to make this work, so my code is added as an importable module?

The answer is unequivocally to use `distutils` (and definitely not `ln`).

> In production, I just create a symlink ...

B-b-but why?  The complexity to do it the Right Way™ is so low!  It even fits in a few lines:

From [The Fine Manual](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html) -- just create a `setup.py` like this:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(name='Distutils',
      version='1.0',
      description='Python Distribution Utilities',
      author='Greg Ward',
      author_email='gward@python.net',
      url='https://www.python.org/sigs/distutils-sig/',
      packages=['distutils', 'distutils.command'],
     )
```

Now you can do fantastic things like `python setup.py install`, `python setup.py bdist_rpm` or `pip install .` -- and not just in the Travis environment but for your project in general.

Comment: For the record, I just spent two hours trying to sort this out for my package. Warning to others: It's not this simple. (Nothing is this simple.)

Comment: @mlissner If it wasn't this simple, what was missing from this solution?

Comment: this doesn't actually fix travis' issues though

Answer (score 8):

To be quick, you can fix the problem more elegantly by adding the following to the `before_script` stage:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$(pwd)
```

The better way(but with a little more effort) is what Brian Cain has suggested, namely, write a `setup.py` file and add `pip install .` to the `install` stage.

Or if you're using a makefile you can have command that does it as the following one.

```
test:
    $(shell export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$(pwd))
    python setup.py test
```

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly not optimal, but it worked. In my .travis.yml file, I added the following line to the `install` attribute:

```
 - ln -s `pwd` $(dirname `which python`)/../lib/python2.7/site-packages/my_module
```

This basically finds the directory where Python is installed and then adds `my_module` as a symlink in there. Happy to hear a better answer, cause this one feels super fragile.

**Update**: See the answer by @Brian Cain for a much better solution.

Comment: Only this could solve my issue with this test repo: https://github.com/alirezahajibagheri/pets_package, so appreciate that. However, I am wondering if you were ever able to solve your issue with other suggestions/answers posted here?

Answer (score 2):

In complement of @Brian-Cain answer, you can also use `setuptools` instead of `distutils`. As of writing, `distutils` is being phased out, and `setuptools` is being used as a replacement, even though `setuptools` is not yet in standard library.

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='Foo',
      version='0.0.1',
      description='Python Distribution Utilities',
      author='',
      author_email='',
      url='',
      packages=find_packages(exclude=['contrib', 'docs', 'tests*']),
     )
```

For a quick tutorial on making a `setup.py` with `setuptools`:
https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/distributing-packages/

For a quick real example: https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/blob/master/setup.py

Answer (score 0):

It's more likely necessary to add `/home/travis/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` to `PYTHONPATH` in `before_script` using `export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/home/travis/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`.