# Python3 module import fails on Travis ci

Tags: python-3.x, import, travis-ci

I have made a Python 3 script for testing a project of mine. [The script](https://github.com/anestv/server-test) has this structure:

```
main.py
myRequest.py
external/
  requests/
    __init__.py
    many files of the library...
```

When I run `python3 main.py` the file `myRequest.py` is imported. Inside that file, I do `import external.requests as reqs`.
This works for me, and also passes on [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org/anestv/server-test/builds/40094422)

However, when I put the above files in the folder `test` of [my project](https://github.com/anestv/pa), the Travis CI job [cannot find the module](https://travis-ci.org/anestv/pa/jobs/47567098#L436):

```
ImportError: No module named external.requests.
```

When I tried running the script in an online IDE (c9, Ubuntu **14.04**, Python **3.4.0**) it was able to import it.
At c9, I have tried doing `from .external import requests as reqs` but it raises a :

```
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import.
```

Adding an empty `__init__.py` file or running `python3 -m main.py` did nothing.

What should I do so that the import is successful at Travis CI?

Comment: I found this article useful for getting a Python project set up with tests and TravisCI integration: http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/08/16/open-sourcing-a-python-project-the-right-way/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add my module to travis-ci pythonpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756134/how-to-add-my-module-to-travis-ci-pythonpath)

Answer (score 5):

I encountered the same issue, so I am posting here in hope to help somebody:

#### Quick Fix

The quick fix for me was to add this line export `PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$(pwd)` in the `.travis.yml`:

```
before_install:
  - "pip install -U pip"
  - "export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$(pwd)"
```

#### Have a setup.py

Having a `setup.py` which should be the default option as it is the most elegant. 
With that you would resolve your relative import issue, try one configured like:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(name='MyPythonProject',
      version='0.0.1',
      description='What it does',
      author='',
      author_email='',
      url='',
      packages=find_packages(),
     )
```

And then add this line in `.travis.yml`

```
before_install:
  - "pip install -U pip"
  - "python setup.py install
```

Comment: I have tried all of the above in my project and none of them seems to be working for me. Could you please take a look and help me out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57661399/using-my-package-throws-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-my-package-in-tra?noredirect=1#comment101771980_57661399