# Using my package throws ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my-package' in Travis

Tags: python, travis-ci, python-importlib

I am trying to use Travis CI for continuous integration but have been dealing with a lot of issues since it is my first time with Travis. Lately, I am running in to the following build fail:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my-package'
```

Which happens when in the following line of code in my `db.py` file:

```
import importlib
db_conf = importlib.import_module("my-package.conf.db_conf")
```

I should mention that I am using `importlib` since my repository has dashes in its name and based on suggestion in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8350853/how-to-import-module-when-module-name-has-a-dash-or-hyphen-in-it), I started using that package.

Right now, my project structure looks like the following:

```
my-project
├── conf
├───── db_conf.py
├── lib
└───── db.py
```

So as you can see I am trying to import `db_conf.py` from `conf` directory and running into no module named issue. I have been stuck with this for the past couple of days and have found the following posts on it: [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25756134/how-to-add-my-module-to-travis-ci-pythonpath) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28108971/python3-module-import-fails-on-travis-ci?rq=1). Problem is that I have tried all those methods and none of them seems to be working for me. Here is how my `.travis.yml` and `setup.py` files look like:

**.travis.yml**

```
language: python
python:
  - 3.7
env:
  global:
    # TRAVIS TESTING CONFIGURATION
    - COMMIT=${TRAVIS_COMMIT::8}
    - CGO_ENABLED=0
    - GOOS=linux
    - GOARCH=amd64
before_script:
  - export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$(pwd)
before_install:
  - python --version
  - pip install -U pip
  - python setup.py install
  - pip install -U pytest
  - pip install codecov
install:
  - pip install ".[test]" . # install package + test dependencies
script:
  - pytest
  - codecov
after_success:
  - codecov
```

And **setup.py**:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

INSTALL_REQUIRES = [
    'pandas',
    'pyspark',
    'pyhdfs',
    'sqlalchemy',
    'configparser',
    'python-dotenv',
    'mysqlclient'
]
TEST_REQUIRES = [
    # testing and coverage
    'pytest', 'coverage', 'pytest-cov',
    # to be able to run `python setup.py checkdocs`
    'collective.checkdocs', 'pygments',
]

with open('README.md') as f:
    README = f.read()

setup(
    author="John Doe",
    author_email="john.doe@gmail.com",
    name='my-package',
    license="MIT",
    description='Supports my processes',
    version='1.0.0',
    long_description=README,
    url='https://github.com/my-user-name/my-package',
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    python_requires=">=3.5",
    install_requires=INSTALL_REQUIRES,
    extras_require={
        'test': TEST_REQUIRES + INSTALL_REQUIRES,
    },
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 3 - Alpha',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.7',
        'Topic :: Software Development :: Build Tools',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
    ],
)
```

Is there anything that I am missing here? Am I doing something wrong? Any help or any lead to the right direction is much appreciated because this is driving me nuts.

Comment: what happens if you change to `db_conf = importlib.import_module("my_package.conf.db_conf")`? setuptools change '-' to '_'

Comment: Did not help. Same issue: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_package'`

Comment: make sure you have `__init__.py` in your python directories. I am not familiar with `importlib` and the use of `-` in package name. Maybe try a simpler example from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#examples) and check if it works on your PC then on Travis. That might help you debug.

Comment: I want to add to what @Sylhare wrote. " make sure you have __init__.py in ALL your python directories." I had similar issue and only after I added __init__.py in all of them, the issue got resolved.